# Problem when install home-brew on Mac m2 Monterey

Tags: macos, homebrew

today I setup for home-brew. but when I try install on my MacBook m2 Monterey have problem.

here my problem ?

fuadazharibrahim@fuads-MacBook-Pro ~ % brew list
zsh: command not found: brew
fuadazharibrahim@fuads-MacBook-Pro ~ % /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
==> Checking for `sudo` access (which may request your password)...
Password:

```
==> This script will install:
/opt/homebrew/bin/brew
/opt/homebrew/share/doc/homebrew
/opt/homebrew/share/man/man1/brew.1
/opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/opt/homebrew/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
/opt/homebrew

Press RETURN/ENTER to continue or any other key to abort:
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown -R fuadazharibrahim:admin /opt/homebrew
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
/bin/bash: line 234: /usr/local/bin/git: Bad CPU type in executable
Failed during: git init -q
```

my question is how to fix my issue ?

Comment: I have the same problem. I am going to update Monterey to the very latest and hope the problem goes away. I will report back.

Comment: I updated to Ventura 13.2 and it didn't seem to help.

Comment: Eventually it worked for me, although I wasn't totally sure why, I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75406328/5783745) was what did it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally confident in this answer but I hope it helps others (I can't re-create the problem to test my solution - if this solution works for you, please report back).

#### What worked for me

I *think* what solved for me was getting my terminal to use the right git binary:

1. When I ran `which git` it gave an intel version (`/usr/local/bin`), so I needed to remove it.
2. I removed that git binary, located in `/usr/local/bin` by running:

```
rm /usr/local/bin/git
```

3. In a **new** terminal window, I ran `which git` and it gave `/usr/bin/git` instead.
4. Now I tried the homebrew [install script](https://brew.sh/) again and it worked this time

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

Note: I tried a few other things in between which I don't *think* helped, so I'm not 100% confident in this answer, but I hope it gives some ideas that may help.

Also note: if you don't want to delete your `/usr/local/bin/git` file, you could simply move it somewhere else while you try it out.

Answer (score -1):

The error you obtained implies that there is a problem with your `git` executable. You should:

- Check if git is installed (properly) on your device. This can be done by running `which git` on your terminal.
- If git is not installed (or if its path is incorrect), you need to install/reinstall `git` manually through this link: https://git-scm.com/downloads. It will then direct you to this site to download the installer: https://sourceforge.net/projects/git-osx-installer/.
- Run the installer and it should download+install git properly.

You can then proceed with the homebrew installation. Hope this helped :)

Comment: I have the exact same issue on a new Mac Mini M2 Pro. I don't think the issue is git. I have:

~ % which git
/usr/local/bin/git
~ % git --version
git version 2.37.1 (Apple Git-137.1)