# Can't install homebrew on new MacBook

Tags: macos, homebrew

Hey so I just got a new MacBook and tried to install homebrew. However only thing I get when try to install it from the command I found on the website is an error like displayed below.

```
zsh: no such file or directory: /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

maybe someone can help me out with this. Thanks

Comment: see if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74686453/problem-when-install-home-brew-on-mac-m2-monterey/75406328#75406328

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have extra quotes around your command. Are you pasting the commands to the terminal window? Please paste only `/bin/bash -c ...` without any additional quotes.

The problem is, that `zsh` is not running command `/bin/bash` with arguments `-c ...`, but instead it tries to find filename with spaces and parameters that matches the whole line (which it cannot find).

Comment: with this `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)` I get a error which says `zsh: no such file or directory /bin/bash -c`

Comment: In that case, you can debug what's happening. First run `curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh > install.sh`, which should produce a `install.sh`-file to your directory. Then run `/bin/bash install.sh` and see what happens.